# Share scripts and profiles with Dropbox

Tags: bash, dropbox

I'm new to bash, but eager to learn.
Right now I'm stealing useful scripts from other ppl and are wondering where I should put them. So I have a bunch of *.sh files, but don't know where they should go. To make it even more useful I would like a way to share them with my other puter with Dropbox. Is it as simple as linking the dropbox folder to the right place?

Sincerly 
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scripts are "general purpose" the best place to put them is in `~/bin` then they always will be available from the cmd-line (i.e. if that folder is in $PATH)

One approach is to use mercurial via [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or git via [github](https://github.com/)

Create an account there and add your scripts. There are many advantages to this approach, some of them are

- all your scrips are just e.g. a `git clone` away if you are on a new machine.
- with a e.g. `git pull` your environment is updated to the latest
- everything is under SCM management, which means you can merge, diff, commit everything you do.

After a while you will probably add your dotfiles there as well (that is what I do), then whenever I'm forced to use a new machine, it will only take seconds to set up my favorite environment! There are many post here on SO about managing your dotfiles, just search for that term and start reading...

Comment: I think i follow.
So I can put like .bash_profile and all my userscripts into github and just by issuing a command they will all be update to the lates version?

Comment: @Runar best way to say thanks here on SO is to do an "upvote" of the answer (the triangle) and if you really like the answer, click accept, the green thingie ;-)

Comment: @Runar, yes. If you commit something from one machine (1 cmd) and push it to github (1 cmd), you can update any other machine with the latest updates (again 1 cmd)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Dropbox, you might consider making a `bin` folder there and adding that directory to your PATH. You could also make a universal bash_profile file and put it on Dropbox. That's what I do. Not to be self-promoting, but I blogged about it here: https://blog.iharder.net/2011/03/17/bash-profile-sharing-and-useful-scripts/trackback/

Important lines for your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bashrc` on some systems) file:

`test -r ~/Dropbox/bin/bash_profile && . ~/Dropbox/bin/bash_profile`

`export PATH=~/Dropbox/bin:$PATH`

-Rob